# settings for editing in cs4

Tags: video, editing, premiere, codec

What initial setting should I be using in Premiere CS4 if I shot video on a Samsung HMX-q10 camera but shot in standard definition? When I tried DV NTSC the video looks very bad, like it's somewhat pixellated. When I view it on Windows media player the video looks good.
The properties on the clips are: 720x480 59 fps.

Comment: Could you maybe include a screenshot of how the video looks when imported in a DV NTSC sequence? Your footage seems to be NTSC as it is 720x480 interlaced (according to the specs of the camera).

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a de-interlace and make sure that the preview window is at full quality.  If you play back interlaced footage as progressive without deinterlacing, then every other frame only has half the normal information which would look pretty bad.  You should be able to adjust it under Interpret Footage from the footage properties.